# How to manage a list of tags on the server with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have some objects in a collection that carry tags:

```
var Obj = new Meteor.Collection('objects');
Obj.insert({ name: 'object1', tags: [] });
```

I want to maintain on the server a collection of all unique tags used, across the objects in the collection. I do this through another collection of tag families (because I want to maintain multiple separate tag lists for `Obj` and other collections):

```
var TagFamilies = new Meteor.Collection('tagfamilies');
TagFamilies.insert({ name: 'obj', taglist: ['tag1', 'tag2'] });
```

(Assume 'tag1' and 'tag2' have been already added to the tag family for sake of example)

Typically, I would update an object's tags like this:

```
Obj.update({ name: `object1` }, { $set: { tags: ['tag1', 'tag3'] } });
```

After that, I expect `taglist` to hold `['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']`.

What is the most efficient way to add new tags to `taglist` without duplicates?

I can think of the following (but different options are welcome):

1. Create a specific `Meteor.methods`, but then my client code needs to differentiate if I want to add tags vs. update other *regular* attributes of `Obj` through `Meteor.Collection.update`
2. Hook up specific code in the `Meteor.Collection.allow` function, but then it will run for every update to the `Obj` (performance hit) and `allow` does not really seem really to be the right place for such code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer on another forum, posting it here for the record. On the server, do the following:

```
TagFamilies.update({ name: 'obj' },
       {$addToSet: {taglist: {$each: ['tag1', 'tag3ect1']}}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var ObjId = Obj.findOne({name:object});

Obj.update({ _id: ObjId._id }, { $push: { tags: 'tag3' } });
```

Instead of using `$set` think about using `$push` to add new ones. Or use set and create a merged array. (You do need to check that tag1 is already there). You can use something like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) (added with `meteor add underscore`) to tell you what isn't there

*client side js*

```
newTags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
var Tags = ObjId.tags.concat(newTags)  //Merge the two arrays
Tags = _.uniq(Tags); //Get rid of duplicates
Obj.update({ _id: ObjId._id }, { $set: { tags: Tags } });
```

(From the client meteor requires anything running `update` and `remove` to have an ID to determine what its going to modify so you need to use `findOne` to get that first.

Concerning the security its best to make a `Meteor.allow` rule because it delivers the best experience to the user. Using a meteor.call/method doesn't incorporate latency compensation so its going to be a bit slower while waiting for the callback. (You only check to see if its an array and the data isn't malicious) But you can insert the tags on the client

Comment: Thanks for this, but you are essentially addressing how to create a list of unique tags. What I am after is to automatically update, on the server, the second collection (`TagFamilies`) when new tags are `$set` or `$push` into elements of the `Obj` collection